# want to integrate amazon mws with my pesonal website's inventory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

i want to integrate my product's website with amazon seller and mws account to -

- List orders in amazon,
- Get up-to-date for order placed buy any user into my database
- getting details of order placed by customer at amazon and update products into my database
- and other mainly operation related to product's buy and sell updating into my Database, as it's sold from amazon and from my personal website.

I'll use nodejs as my backend

Comment: you can do all of that, but what is your question?

Comment: @ScottG i've my admin panel and client side website,  when i add my product from my admin panel, it must be update in client side website and also it needs to be update in amazon store, so customers can also buy products from Amazon.